# jQuery validation custom error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I can't seem to get jQuery validation to use the data-val-lookup attribute held against the input field it is validating:

Here is the code I am using to add the validation class rule.

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('lookup', function (value, element, params) {
        var hiddenId = $(element).attr("id");
        var textBoxId = hiddenId + "_LookupText";
        return !(($('#' + hiddenId).val() == "") && ($('#' + textBoxId).val() != ""));
    });

    $.validator.addClassRules('lookup', { lookup: true });
});
```

Here is what I have for my lookup input fields:

```
<input class="lookup" data-val="true" data-val-lookup="Campaign must be a valid lookup item" data-val-number="The field Campaign must be a number." id="CampaignId" name="CampaignId" type="text" value="" />

<input type="text" id="CampaignId_LookupText" class="form-control" name="CampaignId_LookupText" />
```

The validation works but I get "Warning: No message defined for CampaignId" instead of the message.

I can specify a default message... but it needs to be field specific (containing the field name).

If I add a "title" attribute to the field, it is using this as the error message... but I want it to use data-val-myvalidation instead as this seems to be convention.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `data-msg-<rule>`

```
data-msg-lookup="Campaign must be a valid lookup item"
```

---

The customMessage method is as follows

```
customDataMessage: function (element, method) {
    return $(element).data("msg" + method[0].toUpperCase() + method.substring(1).toLowerCase()) || $(element).data("msg");
},
```

Comment: Awesome. This fixed it! Why does the rest of the MVC populated validation use data-val-validationname?